# How do you localize an app with multiple languages in one country?

Tags: ios, localization, app-store, country, keyword-search

How does the store know which set of "keywords" to use when someone in that country is searching with that language?

Example: In Canada, there could be people searching French keywords, or English keywords. When someone is searching in the App Store, how does the App Store know which language set of keywords to use? Is it based on the device settings in iOS? iTunes Store/App Store settings on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the device settings. ITunes Connect allows you to configure specific descriptions and **tags** for each language (not country). When the user opens the AppStore and types some keywords the Stores compares that words with the corresponding tags for the user's language.